# Use of multi-strand wire with terminals

Tags: wire, wire-terminals

I have a question regarding multi-strand wires. I use wires starting from 0.34 Sq mm to 6 Sq mm in my electrical cabinets. While connecting these wires in terminals, is it recommended to twist the wires? Could you please explain the pros and cons of twisted wire connections and straight wire connections?

Comment: It depends what regional regulations you are working to.

Comment: What does the data sheet of the terminal block recommend?

Comment: You may wish to investigate "bootlace ferrules", generally better then putting wire directly into the clamp.

Comment: A better solution than twisting is the use of [electric wire ferrules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_wire_ferrule) and a professional crimping tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, always twist the wires. When I was training as an electrician it was explained this way: you want the current to flow between the strands, not through the terminal from one strand to another. It ensures all the copper strands are contacting each other. This is true whether it's multiple strands in one wire, or multiple wires with solid or stranded conductors.